# How to Display div in 3 months content from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have database to date1 will came and that date1 i have added 3 months then that was date2 i wrote the code for if condition but not working

i have already working and write some of the code but not working

```
$createDate = new DateTime($ac_join);
$strip = $createDate->format('d-m-Y');
$effectiveDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($last)));
```

the Output Will came like this

$last Value : 25-04-2019
after added 3 months : 27-07-2019

```
 if($effectiveDate > $last )
{
   // last value to 3 months content not display
}
```

I expected out put is if condition will satisfy 3 months after only diplay the content other wise remain values display

Here is the Code

```
<?php $sql ="SELECT * from `donor_register` ORDER BY `dnr_blood_donate` LIMIT 4 ";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $dnrcount   = $result->num_rows;
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

   $last =  $row['dnr_blood_donate']; 
   $createDate = new DateTime($ac_join);
   $strip = $createDate->format('d-m-Y');
   $effectiveDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($last)));

   if($effectiveDate > $last )     
    {  ?>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
         <div class="single-member">
            <a href="donor-profile.php?did=<?=$did;?>">
               <div class="part-img">
                  <img src="assets/image/donor/<?=$image;?>" alt="Donor image" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;"/>
               </div>
            </a>
            <div class="part-text">
               <a href="donor-profile.php?did=<?=$did;?>">
                  <h3><?=$fullname;?></h3>
               </a>
               <h4>Blood group : (<?=$bgroup;?>)</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="part-social">
               Last Blood Donation : <?=$last;?>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: what is not working ? - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/168d40cf88ca07d4b2888bee3c3d036305db3abc

Comment: larger value but display only 1 record from database here it will display all records

Comment: You should add code how you retrieving data from database. We can't understand where is problem

Comment: here i have two diferent dates 1st :24-07-2019    2nd:25-04-2019  in the above code i see two profiles  but my intention is only display the 3 months after content only i.e, 2nd one only display

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to calculate the deference between two dates and if the deference is grater than 3 months, do an action. In my example, `date_1` is equal to `25-04-2019` and `date_2` is equal to `now`. I want to know whether from `date_1` to `now` passed 3 months or not.

**Here your code:**

```
$date1 = new DateTime("25-04-2019");   //****** This is date_1 and in your code, you get this date from the database.
$date2 = new DateTime();    //****** This is date_2, I assume it is now.

$periodOfTime = 90;  //****** 3 months

if ($date1->diff($date2)->days > $periodOfTime) {
    echo "Three months passed from the date_1";
}
else {
    echo "Less than three months passed from the date_1";
}
```